# I have a chained dropdownbox while alerting the second dropdown box I am getting alert on first box tooo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While selecting a option from second box of a chained drop down box I need to get an alert but I am getting alert while selecting both the boxes.

```
<select id="test" name="test">
    <option value = ""> -- Select One -- </option>
    <option value = "a">car</option>
    <option value = "b">bike</option>
</select>
<select id="test3" name="test3" style="width:40%" onchange="alertInstitute(this)">
    <option value = "aa" class = "a">bmw</option>
    <option value = "ab" class = "a">audi</option>
    <option value = "ba" class = "b">harley davidson</option>
    <option value = "bb" class = "b">royal enfield</option>
</select>
<script>
    $jq("#test3").chained("#test");
    function alertInstitute(select){
        alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: Have you defined $jq intentionally or its typo. Also have you used jquery.chained.min.js . I see its working after update.

Comment: yeah i used both but iam getting alert on both the dropdown boxes

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function () {
   $('#test3').change(function () {
      alert($('#test3 option:selected').text());
   });
});
```